# A topological space whose connected components are locally connected

Tags: gn.general-topology

We say that $X$ is locally connected at $x$ if for every open set $V$ containing $x$ there exists a connected, open set $U$ with $x\in U\subseteq V$. The space $X$ is said to be locally connected if it is locally connected at $x$ for all $x\in X$. Now let $X$ be a compact $T_0$ topological space  whose  connected components are locally connected. Is there any characterization for such a space?

Comment: Could you give some hints at the kind of characterization you are looking for? What kind of property would you relate that to? It seems such a basic property that characterizations might be mere rephrasings, would you be interested in sufficient or necessary conditions?

Comment: @Benoît Kloeckner: I am looking for  some  sufficient and  necessary conditions for this property.

Comment: If the compact space is metrizable, then one can try to characterize such spaces as images under some special maps of the product of the Cantor set and the interval.